# Can't start clockwork recovery image lately

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, clockworkmod-recovery, recovery-mode, rom-manager

"Lately" (like in the last few months), I'm unable to start the Clockwork Mod recovery image on my Nexus S with [Oxygen 2.2.1](http://forum.oxygen.im/viewtopic.php?id=165). When I select "boot to recovery mode" (or want to start a ROM backup) in [ROM Manager Premium](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager.license&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLmtvdXNoaWtkdXR0YS5yb21tYW5hZ2VyLmxpY2Vuc2UiXQ..), it reboots and I see the Android icon. The very first line is red and reads:

**FASTBOOT MODE - NO BOOT OR RECOVERY IMG**

I've (supposedly…) reinstalled the recovery image multiple times and ROM Manager tells me, that I'm on the latest version already (5.0.2.0).

Well…

How do I install the Clockwork Mod recovery image? My phone is rooted, if that's important.

Thanks,
Alexander

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try flashing the Recovery image manually via fastboot, as described in [this](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Nexus_S%3a_Full_Update_Guide#Installing_the_ClockworkMod_Recovery_Image) guide:

> 1. Download the latest version of the ClockworkMod Recovery from [here](http://download.clockworkmod.com/recoveries/recovery-clockwork-5.0.2.0-crespo.img).
> 2. Place the ClockworkMod Recovery Image in the same folder as fastboot (the /tools folder with the Android SDK folder).
> 3. Power the Nexus S down, and hold Volume Up & the Power button until booted into the bootloader. You should see a white screen with
>      three skating androids.
> 4. Connect the Nexus S to the computer via USB. On the computer, open terminal and run: `fastboot flash recovery recovery-clockwork-5.0.2.0-crespo.img`
>
> The ClockworkMod Recovery should now be installed on the Nexus S.

Comment: Thanks A lot!
I just flased the phone via ROM manager and it asked me to reboot. I did the same but, my phone got stuck on bootloader, when i use to click recovery it use to hang on GOOGLE logo. I was so tensed :)
THanks-A-Lot